# ImportError: cannot import name 'DDPPlugin' from 'pytorch_lightning.plugins.environments

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I face trouble with importing DDPP from pytorch plugins:

from lit_models import LitFullPageHTREncoderDecoder
from lit_callbacks import LogModelPredictions, LogWorstPredictions, PREDICTIONS_TO_LOG
from data import IAMDataset, IAMDatasetSynthetic, IAMSyntheticDataGenerator
from util import LitProgressBar, LabelEncoder

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset
from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything, Trainer
from pytorch_lightning import loggers as pl_loggers
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ModelSummary
from pytorch_lightning.plugins import DDPPlugin

installed pytorch version : 2.0.0

I have tried everything, uninstalled it and installed it again. It doesn't work